# Can custom exceptions be created for a webservice operation on netbeans?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish

I am using netbeans glassfish bundle to create a webservice. I am adding operations to the webservice from the design view. In the exception tab I noticed theres no way to create a custom exception and you can only search for a predefined exception. Is this a standard for webservices? Or can I just create my own exception classes and then search for them from this dialogue box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'custom exceptions' as part of a web service.  The dialog does not let you create a custom exception as you are creating your web service.  The dialog will let you choose a custom exception that you have created prior to opening the dialog/creating your web service.

[alt text http://blogs.sun.com/vkraemer/resource/custom-exception.png](http://blogs.sun.com/vkraemer/resource/custom-exception.png)